# Compiler crashes when printing a pointer related code

Tags: c, pointers

Today when learning pointer in C, I have faced a problem. I wrote this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *p="XAD";

    printf("%c\n",(*p));
    printf("%c\n",++(*p));
    return 0;
}
```

First printf() shows correct output and it is ***X***. But for second output, compiler crashes. But why? If (*p) gives 'X'(as expected), then ++(*p) should give 'Y'. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Your program crashes. If the compiler would have crashed your wouldn't even had the program to run.

Comment: You might like to try `printf("%c\n", (*p) + 1);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
char *p="XAD";
```

You create a pointer `p` and assign it to the string literal `"XAD"`. **String literals are immutable**, meaning that it cannot be changed. The `++(*p)` dereferences the pointer `p` and increments it, thus attempting to change the contents of the string literal (Specifically, the first character). Attempting to modify a string literal leads to [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as seen in the C11 standard (emphasis mine):

> **6.4.5 String literals**
>
> [...]
>
> 7. It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined**

---

Fix the problem by either declaring `p` as an array or using `(*p)+1` instead of `++(*p)`. Using the former will not modify the contents of the string literal while the latter does.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `p` points to a *string literal*. Modifying a string literal results in *undefined behaviour* in C.

Change

```
char *p="XAD";
```

to

```
char p[]="XAD";
```

which will allow you to modify it since `p` is an array here.

While `char *p="abc";` is perfectly valid in C, in general, *string literals* should be declared with `const` keyword as you are not allowed to modify it anyway. This will help catch an accidental change. It *should* have been of type *const char[]* but it is of type *char []* is because of "historical" reasons (C++ corrected it).

Or you simply interested in printing a modified value, you can do:

```
printf("%c\n", (*p) + 1);
```

as suggested by [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk), which does what you code attempts to do but without modifying the *string* itself.